# Any way to remove clouds in Armello?

Tags: armello

Is there any way using console commands for example to remove the cloud cover in Armello?  The map feels very 'zoomed in' a lot of the time, and playing at max height puts clouds between you and the board which adds an annoying foggy overlay onto everything.

I've seen a few different commands/solutions listed on the steam forums [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/290340/discussions/0/1636418037473512158/) but these either didn't work for me or led to weird graphical issues.  It's possible I did something wrong, though, it's sort of difficult to follow the instructions in the forum.

Comment: And you noticed the link to [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1687233948) as well? There are three methods mentioned, they all have slightly different orders in which to enter the console commands. Have you tried those?

Comment: Actually don't think I saw that specific guide, I'll go through the steps listed and see if any of those methods do it and report back.  Thanks.